# Protocols that are highly resistant to code injection attacks ?

Tags: protocols, injection

After reading  about language based security, it seems protocols that are defined using context-free or regular grammars are highly resistant to code injection attacks.

Are there any good security protocols that are context-free or regular ?

Comment: I'll hack a Turing machine,  just give me a pair of scissors and some scotch tape.  In the real world,  security is an unsolved problem.

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](http://langsec.org/papers/langsec-tr.pdf) deeply analyzes the problem and introduces a technique called Differential Parse Tree Differential Analysis. You should probably start from there.

Comment: Please consider quoting parts of the PDF to improve your answer as links tends to go dead after some time.

Comment: This paper is the reason behind this question.  I'm looking for a concrete protocol.